# how oracle read date from basic date picker for vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, oracle

hello I'm using oracle & vb.net

this is my code for select statement and I want to display the selected date from interface which i use Basic Date Picker and i assign that as bdp1

```
 Dim queryString As String = "select * from abc where (tran_dttm <= to_date( '" & bdp1 & "' ,'MM/DD/YYYY') and tran_dttm > to_date( '" & bdp1 & "' ,'MM/DD/YYYY')and lpt = '" & ListBox1 & "' and device = '" & strMaterial & "')"
```

Comment: I am not completely sure about what you want to do, do you want to display the result of the query in a Date Picker?

By the way, you should use parameters in your query string to prevent sql injections.

Comment: i insert by basic date picker then i want to display in gridview. 
i try to use parameter like this :
sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(":bdp1", bdp1) but its doesn't work.

Comment: Is it correct that you want to:

1. Insert the date of the Date Picker into the database, using the sql query above
2. Show the inserted date in a GridView

Comment: i want to search the date and my db is oracle.

Comment: Ok, and where do you have trouble doing this?
The SQL isn't working? You can't get it to display?

Comment: i got this. the oracle could not read my input 
ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number

Comment: So the parameters you are passing can't be processed?

Comment: yes it could not be process

Comment: Ok, I think I got what the problem is now.

Use the debugger to analyse how your query string looks after the parameters where added. Then correct the errors in it.

What seems strange to me right away is "ListBox1" in you query string. Did you mean to use ListBox.Selected*?

**You really should use Sql Parameters**, to avoid all of these problems and difficult debugging!

Answer (score 1):

select * from abc where trunc (tran_dttm) = to_date('" & bdp1 & "','MM/DD/YYYY')

Comment: This query is just asking for SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

Parameters should be prefixed with the `:` and should be included as text directly in the command. It is the job of the framework to pass them with their values to the database engine

```
Private Function GetDate(ByVal strMaterial As String, ByVal ListBox1 As String, ByVal bdp1 As Date) As DataSet

    Dim connectionString As String = "Data Source = ***; User ID = ***; Password = **;"
    Dim queryString As String = "BEGIN select * from abc " & _
             "where (tran_dttm <= to_date(:bdp1,'MM/DD/YYYY') and " & _
             "tran_dttm > to_date(:bdp1 ,'MM/DD/YYYY') and " & _
             "lpt = :lb1 and device = :mat); END;"
    Using sqlConnection = New OracleClient.OracleConnection(connectionString)
    Using sqlCommand = New OracleClient.OracleCommand(queryString, sqlConnection)
        sqlCommand.CommandTimeout = 0
        sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter(":bdp1", OracleType.DateTime)).Value = bdp1
        sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter(":lb1", OracleType.VarChar)).Value = lstBox1.SelectedItem.ToString 
        sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter(":mat1", OracleType.VarChar)).Value = strMaterial
        Dim dataAdapter As OracleClient.OracleDataAdapter = New OracleClient.OracleDataAdapter(sqlCommand)
        Dim dataSet As DataSet = New DataSet
        dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet)
        Return dataSet
    End Using
    End Using
End Function
```

The ListBox1 is wrong if it is a control. You should use the SelectedItem property as value for the parameter (a bit of error checking is needed though)

Comment: ok but i get this error >> ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Comment: Try to add a semi-colon at the end of the string command, or better a BEGIN/END;

Comment: like this ??
Dim queryString As String = "select * from abc where (tran_dttm <= to_date(:bdp1,'MM/DD/YYYY') and " & _
        "tran_dttm > to_date(:bdp1 ,'MM/DD/YYYY') and " & _
        "lpt = :lb11 and device = :mat)"; 

if this i still got error

Comment: Run this query directly and formatted in SQL Developer, it will provide additional information about where the problem is and make the debugging process easier.

Comment: By the way, the condition on the date is impossible.